# Inheriting from a class (datetime.date) causes a super().__init__(...) too many arguments TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, super

I am using Python 3.6 and wanted to write a class that extends `datatime.date` and introduces some additional attributes and methods that I need in my code.
The problem is that the initialization does not seem to work properly due to seemingly too many arguments.

Below is the code cut down to the minimum:

```
FORMAT__DD_MM_YYYY = "dd.mm.yyyy"
from datetime import date


class DateExtended(date):
    date_string = None
    date_format = None

    def __init__(self, year: int, month: int, day: int, date_format: str=None):
        super().__init__(year=year, month=month, day=day)
        self.date_format = date_format
        self.date_string = "{:02d}.{:02d}.{:04d}".format(self.day, self.month, self.year)

bla1 = DateExtended(year=2010, month=5, day=3, date_format=FORMAT__DD_MM_YYYY_DOT)
```

Executing it causes the following error:

```
bla1 = DateExtended(year=2010, month=5, day=3, date_format=FORMAT__DD_MM_YYYY_DOT)
TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

What am I doing wrong here and how should that be fixed?

Is it because the `date` is not extending `object`?

---

Side-note: When trying to fix this myself, I have also written a different class which does not inherit from `date` but just creates a `date` object and stores it as one of its attributes:

```
self.date = date(year=year, month=month, day=day)
```

There no problems are encountered.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that `date` is a method, not a class. You can only extend a class with another class, not method.

Comment: @campovski:  `type(date)` is `<class 'type'>`.  Looks like a class to me

Comment: @Billy thanks for bringing this up but you don't understand the output of `type()`. `date` is of type `type`. Try `type(2)` and you get `<class 'int'>`.

Comment: @campovski `date` is a class. Try [`inspect.isclass(date)`](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass). Also my answer wouldn't work if `date` were a function/method. :)

Comment: @MSeifert ooops, my bad... I guess work is exhausting me... You deserve an upvote! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `datetime.date` does the initialization in `__new__`, not in `__init__` and the error comes from the fact that `datetime.date.__new__` only takes 3 arguments, not 4.

So you have to override `__new__` as well:

```
FORMAT__DD_MM_YYYY = "dd.mm.yyyy"
from datetime import date


class DateExtended(date):
    date_string = None
    date_format = None

    def __new__(cls, year: int, month: int, day: int, date_format: str=None):
        # because __new__ creates the instance you need to pass the arguments
        # to the superclass here and **not** in the __init__
        return super().__new__(cls, year=year, month=month, day=day)

    def __init__(self, year: int, month: int, day: int, date_format: str=None):
        # datetime.date.__init__ is just object.__init__ so it takes no arguments.
        super().__init__()  
        self.date_format = date_format
        self.date_string = "{:02d}.{:02d}.{:04d}".format(self.day, self.month, self.year)

bla1 = DateExtended(year=2010, month=5, day=3, date_format=FORMAT__DD_MM_YYYY)
```